# Counting the numbers of characters in a string

Tags: cobol

I have problem by defining numbers of characters in string.
For example I have the following code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. TASK1.
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 SOURCE-STRING PIC X(50) VALUE "  The length of string    ".
01 LATTER-COUNTER PIC 99.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PROCEDURE.
    MOVE 0 TO LATTER-COUNTER
    INSPECT SOURCE-STRING TALLYING LATTER-COUNTER FOR [???]
STOP RUN.
```

What must I write to find the length of SOURCE-STRING (string that is written in value "  The length of string    ").
Length must be 26 characters (including leading spaces = 2 and final spaces = 4).

Comment: COBOL does not have "strings". You have 28 trailing blanks in that field, and all 28 are identical to each other. You have to clarify what you need to do, and why. Use the edit link under your question to add information to it. And `MOVE` is a reserved word, you can't just plop it into the middle of an `INSPECT` and expect anything useful to happen.

Comment: the `MOVE` was clearly a mistake, I've corrected the code

Comment: @sky_diver89 Does one of the provided answers work for you? If yes: please mark it as answer, if no: please comment on the answer what you miss [or edit your question if comments do not work because of reputation].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bill said:

> COBOL does not have "strings". You have 28 trailing blanks in that field, and all 28 are identical to each other.

If you want to know the length including the number of the used trailing spaces but not the trailing spaces in the field then don't `MOVE` something in (or use `VALUE` for it) but initialize the field (for example with `MOVE ALL 'x00' TO FIELD`) and use `STRING` to get the data in (this way you'd even have a "C"-string). This allows you to do an `INSPECT ... BEFORE FIRST x'00'`.

Other options to consider:

- `FUNCTION LENGTH (content)`
- `STRING content INTO ... WITH POINTER LATTER-COUNTER` (must start with 1)

We can give a better answer when you add more information (via edit) to your question (including which COBOL compiler you use).

Comment: To reliably have the trailing binary-zero, the field needs to be one byte longer. FUNCTION LENGTH ( 'literal' ) could well be the answer :-)

Comment: Although complicated by the actual example here, just getting a counted length that discounts trailing spaces (all of them, hence the complication relative to the literal value shown here), is `FUNCTION STORED-CHAR-LENGTH(field)`.  So this isn't an answer, just a comment/hint to anyone with similar but less stringent requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is using `NULL` to indicate end of the string.

First, initialize `SOURCE-STRING` to `NULL`:

```
01 SOURCE-STRING PIC X(50) VALUE NULL.
```

Then, instead of using `MOVE` to move your string to your variable, use the `STRING` statement:

```
STRING "  The length of string    " INTO SOURCE-STRING
```

The first 26 characters are moved into `SOURCE-STRING`, but the remaining characters are left unharmed, leaving `NULL` bytes at the end of the string. Then you can determine where the `NULL` bytes start.

**Alternatively**, you can use `STRING` with a `POINTER` to automatically count the characters moved:

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

 01 SOURCE-STRING PIC X(50) VALUE NULL.
 01 STR-PTR PIC 9(3).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

    MOVE 1 TO STR-PTR
    STRING "  The length of string    "
    INTO SOURCE-STRING
    POINTER STR-PTR
    SUBTRACT 1 FROM STR-PTR
```

`STR-PTR` will contain the length of the actual string. Note that `STR-PTR` must be explicitly set to `1` before using the `STRING` command.

Comment: `VALUE NULL` (I assume you tested) must be an AcuCOBOL Extension. AcuCOBOL has many :-). VALUE LOW-VALUES is the transportable way to do it (with the assumption that no-one rearranges the collating sequence). Why MOVE 1 TO STR-PTR and then SUBTRACT 1 from it later? Why not MOVE ZERO ... and ditch the SUBTRACT? "z-literals" can be used if it is a literal always (appends a binary zero to the literal) but you then always need to ensure the field is one byte longer that otherwise necessary.

Comment: With ACUCOBOL-GT, if we use `ZERO` as value for the `POINTER`, it will not work somehow, see [general rule #4](https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/acucorpproducts/docs/v6_online_doc/gtman3/gt36138.htm) in the documentation. I don't know the details of other runtimes, but I have only access to ACUCOBOL. But indeed, `LOW-VALUES` will probably set the value to a NULL byte. One can also use `X'0'`, I believe.

Comment: You are correct about the POINTER. It is the next available position for data, so has to be greater than zero and less than the length of the field. Not all operating systems have a "NULL" value. By Standard, COBOL only has NULL for things which can be addresses. With a hex-literal, you need to use ALL else you'll get the space-padding. To get the length of a literal, if that is really the task, FUNCTION LENGTH would be the best, it would be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: And if I wont to count the numbers of inputed from consol SOURCE-STRING (including only inputed leading and only trailing spaces). How can I do it?